# Modifying source code to pass failing junit test regarding element order in a collection

Tags: java, junit, collections, java-8

I have a test class called `LibraryTest`. The junit test defined in this class is failing. I want to pass the failing junit test by only modifying my source code and without changing anything in the junit test.

I have the class files *Book.java*

```
public class Book {

    private int id;
    private final String name;
    private final String description;
    private final Category category;
    public Book(int id, String name, String description, Category category) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.category = category;
    }
    
    public enum Category {
          CoreJava,
          Electronics,
          Python,
          Hibernate
       }
    
    // getter and setters too are there
}
```

and *Library.java*

```
public class Library {
    private final Set<Book> books = new HashSet<Book>();
    public boolean addBook(final Book book) {
          return books.add(book);
       }
       
       public Iterator<Book> getBooks() {
          return books.iterator();
       }
}
```

The test class file *LibraryTest.java* is as follows. The junit test `canSortLibrary()` is failing.

```
public class LibraryTest{

   private Library library;
   private Book hibernate1 ;
   private Book hibernate2 ;
   private Book coreJava ;
   private Book electronics ;
   private Book python;

   @Before
   public void setUp() {
     library = new Library();
     hibernate1 = new Book(0, "hibernate1", "hibernate book1", Category.Hibernate);
     hibernate2 = new Book(0, "hibernate2", "hibernate book2", Category.Hibernate);
     coreJava = new Book(0, "coreJava", "written by x", Category.CoreJava);
     electronics = new Book(0, "electronics", "written by y", Category.Electronics);
     python = new Book(0, "Python Book", "written by someone", Category.Python);

     library.addBook(hibernate1);
     library.addBook(hibernate2);
     library.addBook(coreJava);
     library.addBook(electronics);
     library.addBook(python);
   }

  @Test
   public void canSortLibrary() throws Exception {
      final Book[] orderedBooks = new Book[] { coreJava, hibernate1, hibernate2, electronics, python};
      int i = 0;
      final Iterator<Book> books= library.getBooks();
      
      while (books.hasNext()) {
         final Book book = books.next();
         Assert.assertTrue(book == orderedBooks[i++]);
      }
      
   }
}
```

Comment: I understand that you can't change the test, presumably for an assignment, but I will note that when writing your own tests you should avoid `assertTrue(a == b)` because failures don't provide you any helpful information. `assertEquals(a, b)` or `assertSame(a, b)` (depending on which specific semantics) will give you better info in case of failure.

Comment: Hint: The name of the "correct" array is `orderedBooks`. Your `Library` doesn't impose any ordering on the books, and `HashSet` is inherently unordered.

Comment: How to fix this depends on what order the books should be returned in.  If the right order is whatever order the books were added to the library, you could use an `ArrayList` instead of a `HashSet`.  If it's some specific order that depends on the books themselves (for example, by author, then by publication date), you could use a `TreeSet` and a custom `Comparator`.

Comment: The expected order of books should be like orderedBooks array.

Is there a way to do this by overriding hashCode method for Book(not by hard coding in hashCode method)

Comment: No.  There is no way to get a deterministic ordering in a `HashSet`.

Comment: How do you expect the library to know about the `orderedBooks` array?  You never told it to order the books in any particular fashion.  It would be either magic or coincidence if `getBooks()` returned the books in that order.

Comment: There is no indication of how the `Book`s are naturally ordered.  Your internal storage (i.e. `HashSet`) has no established ordering and `Book` does not implement `Comparable`.  Why is [coreJava, hibernate1, hibernate2, electronics, python] the expected order of the books per the unit test? I feel like something is missing from the question.

Comment: @vsfDawg The most probable scenario is that the books should be sorted by category and then by title within a category. But the problem statement does not support this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According your constraints you need to make your `Book` class `comparable` in a very particular way.

*Book.java*

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Book implements Comparable<Book> {
    static String specialOrder[] = {"coreJava", "hibernate1", "hibernate2", "electronics", "Python Book"};

    private int id;
    private final String name;
    private final String description;
    private final Category category;
    public Book(int id, String name, String description, Category category) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.category = category;
    }
    
    public enum Category {
        CoreJava, Electronics, Python, Hibernate
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Book otherBook) {
        int index = Arrays.asList(specialOrder).indexOf(name);
        int indexOther = Arrays.asList(specialOrder).indexOf(otherBook.getName());
        if (index != -1 && indexOther != -1) {
            // both book titles are in the special order array
            // the indices indicate their order
            return Integer.compare(index, indexOther);
        }
        // at least one book title is not in the special array
        // therefore use natural order of String
        return name.compareTo(otherBook.getName());
    }

    // getter and setters too are there
    String getName(){return name;}
}
```

And use a container which maintains the order:

*Library.java*

```java
import java.util.*;
public class Library {
    private final SortedSet<Book> books = new TreeSet<Book>();
    public boolean addBook(final Book book) {
          return books.add(book);
       }
       
       public Iterator<Book> getBooks() {
          return books.iterator();
       }
}
```

Now we are set and here we go:

```
$ javac Book.java Library.java 
$ javac -cp .:junit-4.13.2.jar LibraryTest.java                                          
$ java -cp .:junit-4.13.2.jar:hamcrest-all-1.3.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore LibraryTest
JUnit version 4.13.2
.
Time: 0,003

OK (1 test)

$
```

Comment: @NehaNaik Please accept the answer to close the issue. Thanks for your feedback!